# Using button add two texts in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-button

[image]

To achieve this button feel in android I am using the below Xml code.
But I think there is aneasy way using button. Can anybody solve my issue as I want to append two text in a single button. My motive is to get rid of this layouts.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_near_by"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/map_roundcorners"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nearby_font"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/map_nav_icon"
            android:textColor="@color/text_white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/Text_size_25" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/Margin_10"
            android:text="Nearby"
            android:textColor="@color/text_white" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you need to append the text of the button programmatically? is that what you mean ?

Comment: Well you can simply separate them with spaces...
Otherwise this is the only way

Comment: @Lal that i  know is there any other way to add in XML is my question

Comment: you can add it in `android:text="Nearby"`

Comment: Try to set your two text at run time to button like : button.setText("Text1"+" "+"Text2");

Answer (score 0):

To make a button appear with text and an icon, use the Button class with the android:drawableLeft attribute:

```
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/button_icon"
android:text="@string/button_text" >
```

Comment: but its not an image both are text.